# How to create an ArrayCollection of Objects?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4.5, arraycollection, flex-mobile

I new to flex, I have a class shown below:

```
public class Items extends Object
{
    public function Items(){
        super();
    }

    public var name:String;
    public var count:int;
}
```

How do I create an ArrayCollection of type Items?

Thanks.

Comment: How to create an ArrayCollection of String ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var item1:Items = new Items();
item1.name = "Name1";
item1.count = 5;

var item2:Items = new Items();
item2.name = "Name2";
item2.count = 7;

var items:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([item1, item2]);
```

Another way:

```
var items:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

var item1:Items = new Items();
item1.name = "Name1";
item1.count = 5;
items.addItem(item1);

var item2:Items = new Items();
item2.name = "Name2";
item2.count = 7;
items.addItem(item2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also create these in mxml (inside  if you're using flex 4)

```
<s:ArrayCollection id="theCollection">
    <namespace:Items name="name 1" count="5" />
    <namespace:Items name="name 2" count="6" />
    <namespace:Items name="name 3" count="7" />
    <namespace:Items name="name 4" count="8" />
</s:ArrayCollection>
```

Then reference the array by its id.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your code:

```
var ac : ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
var newItem : Items = new Items();
newItem.name = 'some value';
newItem.count = 1;
ac.addItem(newItem);
newItem = new Items();
newItem.name = 'some other value';
newItem.count = 2;
ac.addItem(newItem);
newItem = new Items();
newItem.name = 'Yet another value';
newItem.count = 3;
ac.addItem(newItem);
...
```

It may be worth nothing that ArrayCollections are not typed in the same way that a Vector may be, so there is nothing you can do to force all items in your collection to be of the Items type.  [Unless you extend ArrayCollection somehow and override the addItem / addItemAt methods to throw errors if the type is wrong.